# ffmpeg error during encoding: EOF timestamp not reliable

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I have noticed that some videos processed by the following command displays an error in the preliminary phase of the process:

> [Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x7fb06cf00d80] EOF timestamp not reliable

All this happens while I'm testing the ffmpeg command line that generates the encoding with the specific required by dash:

```
ffmpeg -y -i inputfile.mp4 -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=60:min-keyint=60:no-scenecut -r 30 -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -t 3600 -vf "scale=-1:$size" -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" format.mp4
```

It work fine with some videos with small duration but by testing with some movies downloaded it give this error and i believe that could be a problem for MP4Box when dashing which other errors.
Does anyone have any notices about it? Is the command line suitable for dash?
Thanks
Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning, which you can ignore. Source filters, like the movie filter, generate this message but the output file is fine.

Comment: Hi Mulvia, thanks for support, this reassures me, it scares me because I intend to send the video in loop (dash live with mp4box),  could i ask to you about the command line, some suggestions for prepare to dash live stream, i see that the flags change a lot in less time, and the documents are not always upgraded, So I'm not sure, Thanks Massimo

Answer (score -1):

> I need video(mp4 file) time per frame. But I lost last data due to EOF error...

My code

```py
import subprocess

frame_time_ori = subprocess.run(['ffprobe', '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', params, '-show_entries', 'frame=pkt_pts_time', '-of', 'csv=p=0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**When running, I get 'EOF timestamp not reliable' error message.
My boss, who is trouble shooter, definitely solved the problem.**

```py
import subprocess

frame_time_ori = subprocess.run(['ffprobe', mp4_file, '-show_entries', 'frame=pkt_pts_time', '-select_streams', 'v', '-of', 'compact=p=0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If anyone get the problem such as mine, Try it.